# how to reference assemblies from included file with msbuild?

Tags: reference, msbuild, .net-assembly

I want to add an assembly reference to many projects.
These projects all include a Common.CSharp.targets file.
Is there any way that I can put the assembly reference in
the included file once? Instead of editing all the other
.csproj files?

This will be better in case we need to change the
reference in the future.

This simple Common.CSharp.targets file below doesn't work
because the reference doesn't appear in Visual Studio 2010
and the project won't compile due to the missing reference.
When I add this reference directly to the .csproj. It works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PostSharp">
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: don't do that in Common.CSharp.targets. Add your own .targets file to all your projects (it's not too hard writing a script for that), and add common properties/items/references tere.

Comment: @stijn That is already my own .targets file already added to all the the projects.

Comment: @stijn The question is what syntax to put into my own .targets file to reference assemblies?  I tried copy/pasting the reference from a .csproj into my .targets. But it didn't show up in the Visual Studio references even after restarting VS.

Comment: References for imported files are relative to the project, not the location of the target file.  Could you include the location of the project, import file, and binary location to help determine why this is not working?  Be sure to read up on the Imports element for caveats specific to your scenario: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx

Comment: Please show a complete minimal sample of what you tried _exactly_ and also tell us where the referenced assembly is relative to the projects